# Find key of object with maximum property value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary of dictionaries like this.

```
d = {
    'a' : {'c' : 1, 'h' : 2},
    'b' : {'c' : 3, 'h' : 5},
    'c' : {'c' : 2, 'h' : 1},
    'd' : {'c' : 4, 'h' : 1}
}
```

I need to get key of the item that has highest value of `c + h`.

I know you can get key of item with highest value in case like this:

```
d = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 }
max( d, key = d.get ) # 'c'
```

Is it possible to use the `max` function in my case?

Comment: In your example, is that supposed to be integer division of a string, or a comment?  Comments in python are `#`, not `//`.

Comment: @SethMMorton It was supposed to be a comment. This is what happens when you work in several languages at the same time :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify your own function for `key` which can do fancy stuff like getting the value for both `c` and `h` and add those up. For example using an inline-lambda:

```
>>> max(d, key=lambda x: d[x]['c'] + d[x]['h'])
'b'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> max(d, key = lambda x: d[x]['c'] + d[x]['h'])
'b'
>>> d
{'a': {'h': 2, 'c': 1}, 'c': {'h': 1, 'c': 2}, 'b': {'h': 5, 'c': 3}, 'd': {'h': 1, 'c': 4}}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `max` to find the key of the item with the highest sum in a dictionary of dictionaries. Just pass `max` a suitable key function:

```
>>> d = {
...     'a' : {'c' : 1, 'h' : 2},
...     'b' : {'c' : 3, 'h' : 5},
...     'c' : {'c' : 2, 'h' : 1},
...     'd' : {'c' : 4, 'h' : 1}
... }
>>> max( d, key=lambda k: d[k]['c'] + d[k]['h'] )
'b'
```